# Enforcement of "anti-sodomy" laws in Qatar

Tags: law, police, lgbt+, qatar

Qatar has some "anti-sodomy" laws on the books, but the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_in_Qatar) on the topic gives the impression they were seldom enforced in the past couple of decades:

> In 1998 an American citizen visiting Qatar was sentenced to six months in prison and 90 lashes for homosexual activity. In the 1990s, Philippine Overseas Employment Administration informed Philippine workers that gay workers were prohibited in Qatar. This was in response to several mass arrests and deportations of Philippine workers in Qatar, for homosexuality.
>
> In 2016 Saudi Instagram star King Luxy was arrested in Qatar for allegedly being homosexual. He spent 2 months in custody before he was released.

Also according to Wikipedia:

> Since 2004, Article 296 of the current [Qatar] Penal Code (Law 11/2004) stipulates imprisonment between 1 and 3 years for sodomy between men. This is a slight revision of the original law that stipulated up to five years' imprisonment for male homosexuality.

Of course there may be a lot of missing data in there between the 1990s and 2016, but is that he case?  There are probably human rights reports that have a fuller picture on the degree of enforcement of anti-LGBT laws in Qatar...

Comment: I don't know the answer, but how laws are enforced for foreigners (especially tourists or famous foreigners) can often be different from how they are enforced for locals. Few prosecutions of international residents may not not imply few prosecutions of Qatari citizens.

Comment: You ask about "anti-sodomy" laws, but your examples have nothing to do with sodomy.

Comment: @gnasher729: Pardon me for asking about technicalities that appear to be obvious to you, but how is male homosexuality not related to sodomy?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Sodomy is an ill-defined term. Sometimes it means "anal sex", sometimes it means "anal or oral sex", sometimes it means "sex with animals", and sometimes it means "any non-procreative sexual activity". None of the above is equal to "homosexual sex".

Comment: @michau: Sorry, I don't buy that argument. Names and specifics please. And frankly, if anyone (who?) actually defines and condemns sodomy as "anal or oral sex", they need a serious reality check.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy See the first sentence in the [Wikipedia article on sodomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy), you can check the references if you wish. As for oral sex, [here](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/is-oral-sex-still-illegal/) you have the term "anti-sodomy laws" used to mean "laws banning oral sex".

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sodomy): "Anal intercourse". [Mirriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sodomy): "anal or oral copulation with a member of the same or opposite sex, also: copulation with an animal". These are modern, not historical, English dictionaries. And the authoritative version of modern-day Qatar laws is in Arabic, so it has nothing to do with the meaning of the English word "sodomy".

Comment: What's with the argument? Whether the laws are against so-called "sodomy" or not is entirely irrelevant to the question. I personally would change it to "anti-homesexuality laws", but regardless the meaning of the question doesn't depend on that.

Comment: @gnasher729: I phrase it like this because Wikipedia says "Since 2004, Article 296 of the current [Qatar] Penal Code (Law 11/2004) stipulates imprisonment between 1 and 3 years for sodomy between men. This is a slight revision of the original law that stipulated up to five years' imprisonment for male homosexuality." I don't know the details of the law myself beyond that.

Comment: Honestly, this is just common sense that indifferent than law enforcement on prostitution.  i.e. 1. Entrapment  2. Privacy invasion 3. Involved member(s) report to the authority. 4.Caught red handed in public area 5. etc.